# To add JButton to JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, jtextarea

How can I add `JButton` on `JTextArea`?
I have such a code, when I print name of country in `JTextField` some information using REST displays on `JTextArea`. But I want to use for this purpose JButton. When user click `JButton` information will be start searching and then display.

```
public class Client extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

protected JTextField textField;
protected JTextArea textArea;
protected static JButton search;

public Client() {
    super(new GridBagLayout());

    search = new JButton("Search");
    search.setBounds(100,190,60,30);

    textField = new JTextField(20);
    textField.addActionListener(this);

    textArea = new JTextArea(10, 20);
    textArea.setEditable(false);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);

    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    add(textField, c);

    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    c.weightx = 1.0;
    c.weighty = 1.0;
    add(scrollPane, c);
}
```

My program show such a window, I want to place my button on the bottom of the window (on the picture).

[image]

Comment: Wait, what? You want to add a JButton to a JTextArea? Physically place the button inside the text area? Why? What problem would that solve? Please clarify your question and your problem.

Comment: Then add the same `ActionListener` to your button like you did with the text field.

Comment: Ok, I just want that when I print name of country in `JTextField` and then click `JButton` some information using REST displays on `JTextArea`. Maybe I should create `JPanel` and add my button there?

Comment: Use a `JEditorPane` or `JTextPane` instead, you can use a hyperlink to which can be clicked or even add components to it...but it still makes you scratch your head

Comment: You already have the panel. Just add the button to it. If you can't get that to work, post a picture of what you want to achieve.

Comment: I add the picture to the post. My program show such a window, I want to place my button on the bottom of the window (look the picture).

Comment: Looks like you just want a [`BorderLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) with the text field on `PAGE_START`, the text area in `CENTER` and the button on `PAGE_END`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what are you expecting exactly, but I wrote this code, I'm not use your code, cause I can't run it, but I think this is that you want.

```
JFrame gui = new JFrame("Button on bottom.");

JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

JTextField textfield = new JTextField();
textfield.setText("Australia");

JTextArea textarea = new JTextArea();
textarea.setText("Australia, -27, 133. AUD");

JButton button = new JButton("Button on bottom.");
button.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 0, 15));
button.setBorderPainted(false);
button.setFocusable(false);
button.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
button.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 140, 255));

panel.add(textfield, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
panel.add(textarea);
panel.add(button, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(gui.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
gui.setSize(300, 300);
gui.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
gui.add(panel);
gui.setVisible(true);}}
```